# Animatronic dragon that comes to life

Tags: story-identification, movie, dragons

So I have no clue what the name of this movie is, I saw it when I was a little kid and can't remember for the life of me the name.

But the tidbits I do remember are as follows: A movie is being made about a dragon and they have this huge impressive dragon animatronic thing they plan to use. This guy wants to help make the movie, this other guy who made the dragon animatronic is like, world famous or something (I think?). Anyway they find the guy who wants in on the movie is able to make the little baby dragons move realistically and they hire him in. So he goes to work for them and works late into the night at which he finds the giant animatronic comes to life and talks with him.

Can anyone name that movie for me? I would love to see it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be an episode of the *Jim Henson Hour*, "[Monster Maker](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_106:_Monster_Maker)". It features a boy and an animatronic dragon which comes to life.

> Teenage Matt Banting wants to work with a famous but eccentric creature/special effects man named Chancey Bellow. He gets more than he bargained for when one of the creatures, the giant dragon-like Ultragorgon, takes Matt under his wing. Matt is forced to confront his inner monsters while working out his issues with his father.

[image: Image of Matt meeting Ultragorgon]

### Trailer

Comment: Oh! That is most definitely it! Thank you so much! I have spent YEARS looking for this, I can't believe it was a Jim Henson production the entire time. >_< I love it! :)

Comment: I lucked out. Several people have asked about it in various parts of the web and I finally found a place where someone provided an answer. :)